# I have an Apple keyboard that isn't recognized by my Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard

I have the wired Apple keyboard that has the numeric keypad.
When I try to use the command or control keys in Cs4....they don't work.
When I checked the keyboard input area in my preferences..it shows a keyboard that looks nothing like the one I'm using.
How can I get my Mac to recognize my keyboard.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port? Or trying the same keys in a different application?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried re-running the Keyboard Setup Assistant? First, [get macOS to "forget" your keyboard](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1620325):

`sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist`

and then reboot your Mac. If it still doesn't recognize the keyboard, you can try [manually running the setup assistant](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1095876)

`sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/KeyboardSetupAssistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Keyboard SetupAssistant`

to see if it detects any keyboards it's not sure about.